# How to unstack the line series on a chart: AMCharts3

Tags: javascript, amcharts

So on my chart I have bars and lines and I want the bar series to be stacked like in the image below but I don't want the line series to be stacked. 
[Example of the current Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt0TF.png)

In the example image, the top line series value for the first 3 points is 100,000 but it sits at 150,000, whereas the bottom line series is valued at 50,000 and sits at 50,000 so I believe they are stacking which I don't want to happen.

I want the chart to look exactly the same but having the line series to sit at the correct value on the yAxis.

```
let {dataProvider, displayCurrency} = this.props;
    var config = {
        "type":"serial",
        "categoryField":"category",
        "fontFamily":"arial",
        "categoryAxis":{
            "gridPosition":"start",
            "title":"Time",
            "titleRotation":0
        },
        "trendLines":[],
        "graphs":[
            {
                "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                "balloonFunction" : formatGraphMoneyBallon("Hedging"),
                "balloonColor": "#000066",
                "fillColors": "#000066",
                "lineColor": "#000066",
                "fillAlphas": 1,
                "id": "coverUpper",
                "title": "Hedging",
                "newStack": false,
                "type": "column",
                "valueField": "hedging"
            },
            {
                "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                "balloonFunction" : formatGraphMoneyBallon("Maximum Additional Hedging"),
                "balloonColor": "#000066",
                "fillColors": "#000066",
                "lineColor": "#000066",
                "fillAlphas": 1,
                "id": "coverAdditional",
                "title": "Maximum Additional Hedging",
                "type": "column",
                "newStack": false,
                "valueField": "maxAdditionalHedging",
                "pattern": {
                    "url": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/patterns/black/pattern5.png",
                    "width": 4,
                    "height": 4
                      }
            }, {
                "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                "balloonFunction" : formatGraphMoneyBallon("Forecasted Cashflows"),
                "fillAlphas": 1,
                "balloonColor": "#B0DE09",
                "fillColors": "#B0DE09",
                "lineColor": "#B0DE09",
                "id": "cfGraph",
                "title": "Forecasted Cashflows",
                "type": "column",
                "newStack": true,
                "valueField": "exposure"
            }, {
                "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                "balloonFunction" : formatGraphMoneyBallon("Policy Minimum"),
                "bullet": "triangleUp",
                "balloonColor": "#014310",
                "fillColors": "#014310",
                "lineColor": "#014310",
                "bulletAlpha": 0.6,
                "dashLength": 7,
                "id": "polMin",
                "valueAxis": "dollarAxis",
                "newStack": true,
                "title": "Policy Minimum",
                "valueField": "minHedge"
            }, {
                "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                "balloonFunction" : formatGraphMoneyBallon("Policy Maximum"),
                "bullet": "triangleDown",
                "type": "line",
                "balloonColor": "#014310",
                "fillColors": "#014310",
                "lineColor": "#014310",
                "bulletAlpha": 0.6,
                "dashLength": 7,
                "newStack": true,
                "id": "polMax",
                "valueAxis": "dollarAxis",
                "title": "Policy Maximum",
                "valueField": "maxHedge"
            }
        ],
        "guides":[],
        "valueAxes":[
            {"id":"dollarAxis","stackType":"regular","title":"Amount " + displayCurrency}
        ],
        "allLabels":[],
        "balloon":{},
        "legend":{
            "enabled":true,
            "useGraphSettings":true,
            "spacing": 0,
            "valueWidth":15
        },
        "export":{"enabled":true},
        "dataProvider":dataProvider
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacking is accomplished through the axis. If you want the lines to not stack, put them in a separate value axis that does not have `stackType` set and link the graphs to the value axis id through the `valueAxis` property. You'll also want to consider disabling the lines' value axis' labels, grid and sync the min/max as well:

```
graphs:[{
  type: "line",
  // ...
  valueAxis: "dollarAxis-line"
 },
  // ...
],
valueAxes: [
  {
    "id": "dollarAxis",
    "includeHidden": true,
     // ...
  },
  {
    "id": "dollarAxis-line",
    "labelsEnabled": false,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 0,
  }
],
"listeners": [{
  "event": "init",
  "method": function(e) {
    // sync axes
    e.chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = Math.max(e.chart.valueAxes[0].max, e.chart.valueAxes[1].max);
    e.chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = Math.min(e.chart.valueAxes[0].min, e.chart.valueAxes[1].min);
    e.chart.valueAxes[1].maximum = Math.max(e.chart.valueAxes[0].max, e.chart.valueAxes[1].max);
    e.chart.valueAxes[1].minimum = Math.min(e.chart.valueAxes[0].min, e.chart.valueAxes[1].min);
    e.chart.validateData();

  }
}]
```

*Edit:*
If you're starting with an empty chart, you may want to consider using the `dataUpdated` event instead so that it will resync the axes after you update the dataProvider. The `validateData` method triggers this event, so you'll want to wrap this call in a conditional that checks for a flag so that the chart doesn't keep calling this method infinitely.

```
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "dataUpdated",
    "method": function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (!e.chart.updating) {
          e.chart.updating = true;
          // sync axes
          e.chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = undefined;
          e.chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = undefined;
          e.chart.valueAxes[1].maximum = undefined;
          e.chart.valueAxes[1].minimum = undefined;
          e.chart.validateData();
          e.chart.valueAxes[1].maximum = e.chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = Math.max(e.chart.valueAxes[0].max, e.chart.valueAxes[1].max);
          e.chart.valueAxes[1].minimum = e.chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = Math.min(e.chart.valueAxes[0].min, e.chart.valueAxes[1].mix);
          e.chart.validateData();
          e.chart.updating = false;
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  }]
```

Demo below:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "categoryField": "category",
  "fontFamily": "arial",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "title": "Time",
    "titleRotation": 0
  },
  "trendLines": [],
  "graphs": [{
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "balloonColor": "#000066",
      "fillColors": "#000066",
      "lineColor": "#000066",
      "fillAlphas": 1,
      "id": "coverUpper",
      "title": "Hedging",
      "newStack": false,
      "type": "column",
      "valueField": "hedging"
    },
    {
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "balloonColor": "#000066",
      "fillColors": "#000066",
      "lineColor": "#000066",
      "fillAlphas": 1,
      "id": "coverAdditional",
      "title": "Maximum Additional Hedging",
      "type": "column",
      "newStack": false,
      "valueField": "maxAdditionalHedging",
      "pattern": {
        "url": "https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/patterns/black/pattern5.png",
        "width": 4,
        "height": 4
      }
    }, {
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "fillAlphas": 1,
      "balloonColor": "#B0DE09",
      "fillColors": "#B0DE09",
      "lineColor": "#B0DE09",
      "id": "cfGraph",
      "title": "Forecasted Cashflows",
      "type": "column",
      "newStack": true,
      "valueField": "exposure"
    }, {
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "bullet": "triangleUp",
      "balloonColor": "#014310",
      "fillColors": "#014310",
      "lineColor": "#014310",
      "bulletAlpha": 0.6,
      "dashLength": 7,
      "id": "polMin",
      "valueAxis": "dollarAxis-line",
      "title": "Policy Minimum",
      "valueField": "minHedge"
    }, {
      "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
      "bullet": "triangleDown",
      "type": "line",
      "balloonColor": "#014310",
      "fillColors": "#014310",
      "lineColor": "#014310",
      "bulletAlpha": 0.6,
      "dashLength": 7,
      "id": "polMax",
      "valueAxis": "dollarAxis-line",
      "title": "Policy Maximum",
      "valueField": "maxHedge"
    }
  ],
  "guides": [],
  "valueAxes": [{
      "id": "dollarAxis",
      "stackType": "regular",
      "includeHidden": true,
      "title": "Amount ($)"
    },
    {
      "id": "dollarAxis-line",
      "stackType": "none",
      "labelsEnabled": false,
      "gridAlpha": 0,
      "axisAlpha": 0
    }
  ],
  "allLabels": [],
  "balloon": {},
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "spacing": 0,
    "valueWidth": 15
  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "dataProvider": [{
      "category": "Category 1",
      "minHedge": 151218,
      "hedging": 111436,
      "maxHedge": 236849,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 272065,
      "additionalHedging": 233236,
      "exposure": 163731
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 2",
      "minHedge": 150517,
      "hedging": 137299,
      "maxHedge": 258805,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 254932,
      "additionalHedging": 183495,
      "exposure": 111847
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 3",
      "minHedge": 158456,
      "hedging": 198219,
      "maxHedge": 231274,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 259615,
      "additionalHedging": 187108,
      "exposure": 168738
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 4",
      "minHedge": 167931,
      "hedging": 173121,
      "maxHedge": 263334,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 260449,
      "additionalHedging": 229972,
      "exposure": 156174
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 5",
      "minHedge": 164449,
      "hedging": 157823,
      "maxHedge": 268980,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 268896,
      "additionalHedging": 180031,
      "exposure": 100893
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 6",
      "minHedge": 166465,
      "hedging": 128504,
      "maxHedge": 241036,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 269858,
      "additionalHedging": 230233,
      "exposure": 117158
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 7",
      "minHedge": 167117,
      "hedging": 110649,
      "maxHedge": 229749,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 262671,
      "additionalHedging": 201500,
      "exposure": 188282
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 8",
      "minHedge": 151167,
      "hedging": 123489,
      "maxHedge": 249919,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 268805,
      "additionalHedging": 206302,
      "exposure": 120797
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 9",
      "minHedge": 154961,
      "hedging": 185898,
      "maxHedge": 269185,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 271949,
      "additionalHedging": 173116,
      "exposure": 184312
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 10",
      "minHedge": 154385,
      "hedging": 141307,
      "maxHedge": 234509,
      "maxAdditionalHedging": 274889,
      "additionalHedging": 216132,
      "exposure": 111974
    }
  ],
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "dataUpdated",
    "method": function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (!e.chart.updating) {
          e.chart.updating = true;
          // sync axes
          e.chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = undefined;
          e.chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = undefined;
          e.chart.valueAxes[1].maximum = undefined;
          e.chart.valueAxes[1].minimum = undefined;
          e.chart.validateData();
          e.chart.valueAxes[1].maximum = e.chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = Math.max(e.chart.valueAxes[0].max, e.chart.valueAxes[1].max);
          e.chart.valueAxes[1].minimum = e.chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = Math.min(e.chart.valueAxes[0].min, e.chart.valueAxes[1].mix);
          e.chart.validateData();
          e.chart.updating = false;
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  }]
});

function generateData() {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    data.push({
      "category": "Category " + (i + 1),
      "minHedge": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000 + 200000),
      "hedging": Math.floor(Math.random() * 150000 + 225000),
      "maxHedge": Math.floor(Math.random() * 250000 + 200000),
      "maxAdditionalHedging": Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000 + 200000),
      "additionalHedging": Math.floor(Math.random() * 150000 + 275000),
      "exposure": Math.floor(Math.random() * 225000 + 375000)
    });
  }
  chart.dataProvider = data;
  chart.validateData();
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
<button onclick="generateData()">Generate Data</button>
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, the only thing is that when disabling/hiding the bar/columns then the value axis disappears.
I also had to edit the lines :
e.chart.valueAxes[0].minimum = Math.min(e.chart.valueAxes[0].min, e.chart.valueAxes[1].mix);
      e.chart.valueAxes[1].minimum = Math.min(e.chart.valueAxes[0].min, e.chart.valueAxes[1].mix);
      and change the .mix to .min unsure if this was just a typo.

Comment: Definitely a typo. The demo had the right code though. As for the value axis disappearing, add [`includeHidden`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#includeHidden) in the visible axis and set it to true. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just an addition to this question. So you make the event happen on "Init", on the page I am using if there is no initial data but data isn't provided until I rerender the page then what event would I use to make sure that each time the data is given that the mix/max of the axis is redone.

For example at the moment the first page having no data sets the axis to be min:0 / Max: 10 but these limits will stay when I swap to the other setting with brings in data and the axis stays at Min:0 / Max: 10 but the real max is 110,000.

Hope the question makes sense.

Comment: Use [`dataUpdated`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataUpdated) instead. Note that `validateData` triggers this event, so you'll want to wrap the code in an if that checks for a flag that gets unset after it syncs the axes or it will otherwise trigger an infinite loop. Answer updated.

Comment: Since the first page is setting the min/max of the values of the axis what seems to be happening is it is in a loop setting the same values. Because the min/max of both valueAxes[0] and valueAxes[1] are 0/10 so each time if goes into this method it just sets the min/max to these same values.

Comment: I don't know if this changes anything but I have found that the first page does receive data but it is always set to 0, so there is only a value of 0 for each series. But once clicking the button to change page then the data has proper values of 100,000+

Comment: You need to unset the `minimum` and `maximum` in your value axes, call `validateData` to enable the automatic axis again, then force/sync the axes to the new automatic values.. I updated the answer again.

Comment: The final edit seems to have worked with some alterations. On each of the chart.valueAxes... = undefined; I had to change to e.chart.valueaxes....
It didn't seem to like the setTimeout so removed that altogether. I also had to add in the other two lines which set the e.chart.valueAxes[0]... to the code.
Once I did all this is seemed to have worked and given the desired outcome. Thanks.